# Wearing tefillin all day

Tags: halacha, tefilin

Someone told me that people avoid wearing tefillin all day because of the fear that one might denigrate the tefillin by passing gas with the tefillin on. If someone feels that he is capable of keeping a clean body throughout the day (not passing gas) or removing the tefillin before passing gas would it be OK for him to wear tefillin all day long?

Comment: Indeed there are many qehillot in Israel (particularly in Yerushalayim) that wear tephillin all day long (save for obviously forbidden times/places like the bathroom).

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/77396/759

Comment: Yeah, it's probably OK, but is it worth the risk? It seems like passing gas in Tefillin is such a severe issue that it many Poskim conclude that we shouldn't wear Tefillin all day due to the risk we may pass gas. One time accidentally passing gas may counteract any benefit of wearing Tefillin for an extended period of time.

Comment: http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/83500

Comment: @Lee Like who???

Comment: @Yehoshua Talmide'i HaGR"A in the Old City IIRC

Comment: Should Tefillin be worn when working from home as well? I assume the original machloket was just about what level of da'at you need - whether it is focussing on holy things or just not around impure things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rav Eliyashiv was asked this and was qouted in Sefer  Vayishma Moshe 2: Teffilin. He was asked  if there is an inyan to wear talis and teffilin all day. He answered that a talis it isnt necessary since one wears a talis katan,and regarding teffilin a person needs a guf naki. He was then asked if one knows with certainty that he will have a guf naki is it them an inyan to do it. He answered "Halevei" that one can do such a thing and if one can do such a thing then a bracha should be upon him.

side question: why isnt this mechzei k'yuharah?
[image]

Comment: There are people though that wear tefillin all day...Are they the lucky ones?

Comment: Is R Elyashiv saying those people who are sure they can guard their bodies are blessed because they are so clean or because he thinks they should wear Tefillin? He never actually says they should wear Tefillin. Seems to be hedging

Answer (score 3):

דעת הגאון מוילנא, הובא בספר כתר ראש לרבי חיים מוואלוז'ין ובספר מעשה רב, שאדם שיכול לשמור את גופו נקי צריך להניח תפילין כל היום, ואמר הגר"א שאם היה לו כח היה יוצא בשווקים וברחובות לעורר אנשים לעשות כך.
אבל גדולי הדורות לא נהגו כדבריו.
תורגם ע"י התרגומון של גוגל

The Gaon of Vilna reported that a person who can keep his body clean should wear tefillin all day long, and the Gra said that if he had the strength he would go out in the markets and streets to make people do so.
But the great rabbis did not follow his example.
Translated by Google Translator

Answer (score 1):

ציטוט ספר כתר ראש
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjPCv.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjPCv.png)

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFazH.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFazH.png)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Can you [edit] your answer to explain what this is an image of and how it answers the question, for the benefit of readers who might not be able to view the image or understand the Hebrew?

Comment: On second thought, it looks like this post is just the source for your other post, so it should really be [edited into that one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/101752/edit).

Comment: לא הסתדרתי עם העריכה, העליתי ארבע תמונות לפי סדר ואני רואה שרק שתי תמונות מוצגות, אשמח אם מישהו יודע איך לערוך בצורה טובה את התשובה.                               I did not get along with editing, I uploaded four pictures in order and I see that only two pictures are displayed, I would be happy if someone knows how to edit the answer well.