# Is there any problem with doing mincha with tefillin?

Tags: shacharis-morning-prayer, mincha-afternoon-prayer

If you're in a rush and a miyan is starting and you're finishing shacharis. And you won't have a minyan mincha later on if you don't do mincha now.

And is there a difference if you're holding right after shmona esrei of shacharis or you're holding later on in shacharis?

Comment: The mitzva of tefillin is an all-day thing, even if they are not commonly worn during any other time than Shacharis. I have heard of some Chassidim wearing tefillin shel Rabbeinu Tom during Mincha.

Comment: Extremely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77392/wearing-tefillin-during-mincha-would-someone-get-a-mitzvah-for-it

Comment: Remember that we also wear tefillin during Mincha on Tisha B'Av.

Comment: @Ezra point is, probably, one of the best-known proofs. One of my friends is disabled. He keeps his tefillin in a shul locker. He relies on someone to drive him to shul daily. One Sunday morning, the weather was bad and they cancelled minyan. When he came for Mincha, he wore his tefillin.

Comment: In your situation, if I understand your question correctly, once someone has finished Shacharit, he can probably remove his tefillin for the mincha that immediately follows.

Comment: The last time for Shacharit and the first time for Mincha are about 20-40 minutes apart.