# Praying without tefillin but not late

Tags: tefilin, zemanim, shacharis-morning-prayer

In a case where one does not have access to tefillin during the proper zman of Shacharit, but will soon after, is it preferable to daven after the zman WITH tefillin, or daven during the proper zman but WITHOUT tefillin?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97105/is-wearing-tefillin-necessary-for-praying/97113#97113

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One who doesn't have access to *tefillin* should certainly pray at the correct time, rather than waiting for *tefillin* and missing the time. (See [Mishnah Berurah 25:14](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berurah.25.14?lang=bi))